# Ubuntu 21.04 Identifies RTX 3080 as RTX 3070

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu

I have windows 10 and Ubuntu 21.04 configured in Dual Boot. I have reached here after facing so many problems with Ubuntu 20.04, after which  I followed this question to setup my current machine that is running Ubuntu 21.04 [NVIDIA RTX 3080 GPU not working with Ubuntu 20.04, Kernel 5.8.0-50-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337433/nvidia-rtx-3080-gpu-not-working-with-ubuntu-20-04-kernel-5-8-0-50-generic)

The current problem I am facing is that Ubuntu detects this GPU as RTX 3070 while in reality it is RTX 3080. I will be using this laptop for machine learning with TensorFlow, cuDNN, and many other libraries that are known for their troubles with mismatching versions and unforgiving compatibility matrices.

**Below are some information that might be relevant**

Laptop: Asus ROG Zephyrus G15

Firmware Version GA503QS.405

Graphics card:

- Nvidia Geforce RTX 3080 laptop GPU (confirmed through MyAsus tool, windows task manager, Nvidia control Panel, and BIOS)
- AMD Radeon Graphics

I have the following disabled from the BIOS:

- Secure boot
- Fast Boot
- Asus Erp (Power Management utility that turns off the discrete GPU)
- Asus Armory Crate (Tool that switches between integrated GPU and the discrete GPU)

ubuntu-drivers devices output

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000249Csv00001043sd00001622bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GA104M [GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile / Max-Q 8GB/16GB]
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

nvidia-smi output

```
$ nvidia-smi
Fri May 28 16:57:28 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.73.01    Driver Version: 460.73.01    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 308...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   50C    P0    21W /  N/A |      5MiB /  7982MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1099      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

[Software & Update window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D6oU.png)

Please let me know how can I help you help me. Thanks in advance.

**Update**

lshw -C display output

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for ahmed: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GA104M [GeForce RTX 3080 Mobile / Max-Q 8GB/16GB]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=2560x1440 visual=truecolor xres=2560 yres=1440
       resources: iomemory:f80-f7f iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:122 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:f800000000-fbffffffff memory:fc00000000-fc01ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:fc000000-fc07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Cezanne
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: c4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:55 memory:fc10000000-fc1fffffff memory:fc20000000-fc201fffff ioport:c000(size=256) memory:fc500000-fc57ffff
```

lspci | grep -i vga output

```
$ sudo lspci | grep -i vga
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA104M [GeForce RTX 3080 Mobile / Max-Q 8GB/16GB] (rev a1)
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne (rev c4)
```

Interestingly both show RTX 3080, I will go ahead and ignore this until a related problem appear and will update accordingly.

Comment: `nvidia-smi` identifies it as 3080. Unless you discover some problems related to this, I would simply ignore the *problem*.

Comment: Also, what is the output of `sudo lshw -C display` or `sudo lspci | grep -i vga`?  To me this sounds like a bug in the way it reports.  You might want to file a bug report against `ubuntu-drivers`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I updated the question to include @Terrance suggestions and interestingly both showed RTX 3080. Also, I will submit a bug for this. For now, I will go with your suggestion to ignore the problem until I discover something related to this down the road.