# Are New Updates Going to Wreck 22.04.1 installation (running NVidia drivers)?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, graphics, 22.04

**Background**
Two days ago I started up computer & it was stuck with 1 screen at 1024x768.

I had to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch and [I posted that here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437047/kernel-update-wont-allow-nvidia-1660-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04-how-do-i-fix/).

Today, I started the computer again and it was back at 1024x768 with only one screen available again.

I got it fixed (as I wrote up on the answer at the link above.
I had to choose an older NVidia driver for my 1660.

**New Updates**
Now I see there are new updates -- this is what started the entire problem.

[image: ubuntu updates]

I'm wondering if installing these updates are going to corrupt my system so that I cannot run my NVidia with 2 screens and a good (high) resolution?

I'm just not sure if I should ignore updates somehow or if I'll always be able to choose the older 470 driver??

Comment: You need the updates. I suggest your system was never corrupted and a re install was not required. What most likely happened was a new kernel got installed in the update. Simply going back to the old kernel would have fixed it. I suggest accept the update and if you have an issue come back and let someone help you. You can not have a stable and secure system if you do not do the updates.

Comment: That's a good answer, however, did you see my original post and the image where I attempted to go back to various kernel versions and all failed to recognize the graphics card?

Comment: All that means is you need to install the right driver for the GPU. Again no reason to reinstall.

Comment: Ok, sounds good, plus I'm a willing guinea pig.  Updating now.

Comment: I will make an answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You need the updates.

I suggest your system was never corrupted and a re install was not required.

What most likely happened was a new kernel got installed in the update. Simply going back to the old kernel would have fixed it. I suggest accept the update and if you have an issue come back and let someone help you. You can not have a stable and secure system if you do not do the updates.

If it was not a new kernel that caused the issue you may simply have had the wrong driver for the GPU.

When doing the install use the additional drivers and install the one that is suggested for your card.

Comment: Dropping back to an older kernel is not likely to fix the resolution problem since these days, installing an Nvidia driver module in the latest kernel removes all the Nvidia driver moduels for older kernels. The older kernels then have to use the nouveau driver.

Comment: <I suggest your system was never corrupted and a re install was not required.> Clearly it was since the resolution dropped to 1024. I had a similar experience and instead of reinstalling I had to purge nvidia drivers and reinstall since there seems to be a bug with ubuntu-drivers that was recently introduced. Using the additional drivers install was pointless in this case and although it is the default path it doesn't mean it always works.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and installed the latest updates and since I had previously chosen the driver (shown below) for my NVidia 1660 everything worked out fine.  No corruption.

[image: nvidia driver]

Comment: A Geforce GTX 1660 can run with 515 as recommended by Nvidia themselves.

Comment: where is it reccommended?  How would I know that?  Also, I was running fine with 520 for many months until this.  
I'm just really not sure how I would know which one.  Please provide link thanks

Comment: Recommended at nvidia.com as always. Search for drivers, select your specific chipset from the dropdown menus and the OS then it'll show the currently recommended driver which, again, is 515, not 520.

Comment: It goes without saying that the recommendation above is to **check** the recommended version, NOT to install from there. Always install as you did or by any other mean that relies on the official Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Well, when I did the full clean install of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS it asked me if it should install drivers automatically and the Ubuntu installation chose the incorrect 520 driver and that is the start of woes for an end-user. But I also understand that Ubuntu is not a consumer product so I'm ok with that. But other users who don't have as much experience are going to experience pain.

Comment: Most of the time it choose the best version but occasionally it chooses a newer than recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended suggestions did not work for me.

OP mentioned that they reinstalled the system. This is fine for most things, but we are on LTS for a reason and a reinstall was not an option for me.

It seemed like the reinstall fixed the issue rather than the accepted answer.

## System details

OS: 22.04.1

Kernel: 5.15.0-46-generic

GPU: Nvidia 3080

## Symptoms

Like OP I also ran a standard install and fell back to 1024 resolution.

I did not change drivers

I was not given a kernel update

I also tried to change to older drivers `510` and then back to my recommended driver `515` but without any success.

I did not reinstall the os.

## The problem

Starts with `ubuntu-drivers`

The UI for 'Additional drivers' runs this command `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

This returns an error [to be reported].

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 513, in <module>
    greet()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 432, in autoinstall
    command_install(config)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 187, in command_install
    UbuntuDrivers.detect.nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook(to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py", line 839, in nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook
    with_nvidia_kms = version >= 470
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment
```

## The solution

What worked for me was a purging of the nvidia packages and a manual purge of the drivers and a manual driver install.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*cublas*" "cuda*"
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*nvidia*"
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo apt autoremove
sudo reboot
```

Then installed my recommended nvidia drivers after checking the official recommenedations here https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx

For my card the recommended driver is 515 so

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515
```

Those instructions came from this other helpful post [NVIDIA RTX 3080 GPU not working with Ubuntu 20.04, Kernel 5.8.0-50-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337433/nvidia-rtx-3080-gpu-not-working-with-ubuntu-20-04-kernel-5-8-0-50-generic)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).