# NVidia drivers simply do not work after update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I recently updated my system, as I do routinely - but, unfortunately, it seems to have broken my NVidia drivers, as they simply do not work now. I have the option to install them, under software & updates and additional drivers, and the process seems to work normnally - but, when I restart my computer, it's locked on a low resolution, and all of the NVidia utilities fail to connect to the driver. If I switch to the x Org open source drivers, they work, though I have to use xrandr to fix the overscan. But the open source drivers only support OpenGL up to version 3.20, and I need higher versions for a video game I am programming. And probably to play video games as well, though I haven't actually checked that part.

Anyway, I have tried uninstalling the NVidia driver and reinstalling it several times, and have tried several different versions - 470, 515, 520, and 515 server all have the same problem. I was using 515 just fine before all this started, and it was working fine.

The system is Xubuntu 22.04, newest version, using an NVidia 1050ti. If you need any more information from me, just ask!

Some basic information:

```
(base) angle@Sager:~/Desktop$ lsb_release --all
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:    jammy



01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

(This is using the X Org driver again, so my resolution isn't awful while I try and debug the damn thing. Can get this for the NVidia driver too, but IIRC it was basically the same.)

```
(base) angle@Sager:~/Desktop$ glxinfo -B
name of display: :0.0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: nouveau (0x10de)
    Device: NV137 (0x1c82)
    Version: 22.0.5
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 4077MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.3
    Max compat profile version: 4.3
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: nouveau
OpenGL renderer string: NV137
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.0.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.3 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.0.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20

(base) angle@Sager:~/Desktop$ neofetch
           `-/osyhddddhyso/-`              angle@Sager 
        .+yddddddddddddddddddy+.           ----------- 
      :yddddddddddddddddddddddddy:         OS: Xubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 
    -yddddddddddddddddddddhdddddddy-       Kernel: 5.17.0-1020-oem 
   odddddddddddyshdddddddh`dddd+ydddo      Uptime: 26 mins 
 `yddddddhshdd-   ydddddd+`ddh.:dddddy`    Packages: 5055 (dpkg), 11 (brew), 34 
 sddddddy   /d.   :dddddd-:dy`-ddddddds    Shell: bash 5.1.16 
:ddddddds    /+   .dddddd`yy`:ddddddddd:   Resolution: 1920x1080 
sdddddddd`    .    .-:/+ssdyodddddddddds   DE: Xfce 4.16 
ddddddddy                  `:ohddddddddd   WM: Xfwm4 
dddddddd.                      +dddddddd   WM Theme: Default 
sddddddy                        ydddddds   Theme: Greybird [GTK2/3] 
:dddddd+                      .oddddddd:   Icons: elementary-xfce-darker [GTK2/ 
 sdddddo                   ./ydddddddds    Terminal: xfce4-terminal 
 `yddddd.              `:ohddddddddddy`    Terminal Font: Monospace 12 
   oddddh/`      `.:+shdddddddddddddo      CPU: Intel i5-6500 (4) @ 3.600GHz 
    -ydddddhyssyhdddddddddddddddddy-       GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 
      :yddddddddddddddddddddddddy:         Memory: 2342MiB / 24002MiB 
        .+yddddddddddddddddddy+.
           `-/osyhddddhyso/-`
```

After I switch over to NVidia-470:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

(base) angle@Sager:~/Desktop$ glxinfo -B
name of display: :0.0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Mesa/X.org (0xffffffff)
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 22.0.5
    Accelerated: no
    Video memory: 24002MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 4.5
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.0.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.0.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20

(base) angle@Sager:~/Desktop$ neofetch
           `-/osyhddddhyso/-`              angle@Sager 
        .+yddddddddddddddddddy+.           ----------- 
      :yddddddddddddddddddddddddy:         OS: Xubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 
    -yddddddddddddddddddddhdddddddy-       Kernel: 5.17.0-1020-oem 
   odddddddddddyshdddddddh`dddd+ydddo      Uptime: 10 mins 
 `yddddddhshdd-   ydddddd+`ddh.:dddddy`    Packages: 5075 (dpkg), 11 (brew), 34 
 sddddddy   /d.   :dddddd-:dy`-ddddddds    Shell: bash 5.1.16 
:ddddddds    /+   .dddddd`yy`:ddddddddd:   Resolution: 1024x768 
sdddddddd`    .    .-:/+ssdyodddddddddds   DE: Xfce 4.16 
ddddddddy                  `:ohddddddddd   WM: Xfwm4 
dddddddd.                      +dddddddd   WM Theme: Default 
sddddddy                        ydddddds   Theme: Greybird [GTK2/3] 
:dddddd+                      .oddddddd:   Icons: elementary-xfce-darker [GTK2/ 
 sdddddo                   ./ydddddddds    Terminal: xfce4-terminal 
 `yddddd.              `:ohddddddddddy`    Terminal Font: Monospace 12 
   oddddh/`      `.:+shdddddddddddddo      CPU: Intel i5-6500 (4) @ 3.600GHz 
    -ydddddhyssyhdddddddddddddddddy-       GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 
      :yddddddddddddddddddddddddy:         Memory: 1911MiB / 24002MiB 
        .+yddddddddddddddddddy+.
           `-/osyhddddhyso/-`
```

Comment: I've had numerous problems over the past few days and here is the definitive answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437490/are-new-updates-going-to-wreck-22-04-1-installation-running-nvidia-drivers/1437495#1437495

Comment: That doesn't really address my problem though. I'm using all the newest versions of all software available to me, and I still have problems. I will try some older NVidia drivers though, see if they get me anywhere?

Comment: Haha nope, tried 470, same thing. :/

Comment: I think I had the same problem two days ago, because I chose alternate drivers but couldn't get it to work.  But, look real close at the text of the driver: There are 2 different 470 drivers -- 1 says SERVER.  I think I may have been picking the server one and it was failing.  Check & see if that is what is happening in your case too?  Good luck

Comment: Which update "broke your NVidia drivers"? How do you know for sure that an update caused your problem? How were they installed in the first place? What are the exact actions you've taken to try to resolve this so far? Please use exact details. For example, you should include in your command a complete list of all of the commands that you've run. The appropriate NVidia driver should have been installed during system installation. Manually installing drivers after-the-fact is known to cause issues. Can you please provide more/clearer details?

Comment: I was definitely not using the server 470 drivers. As for the update a couple days ago - I wasn't paying a ton of attention. It was pretty routine, except that it didn't want to update a handful of packages, and then it was wanting to repeatedly install and uninstall some packages. As for the drivers themselves, I've changed drivers using the 'Software & Updates - Additional Drivers' tab multiple times to solve other problems, and it always started working eventually. I just upgraded my system to 22.10, so I'll see if that solved the issue or not?

Comment: Okay, after updating my distribution, when I changed my driver (version 515, non-server), it prompted me to restart my computer, which it didn't do before (I was doing that part manually) - and now that I have, it seems to be working. Supports the version of OpenGL I need and everything.

Answer (score 0):

I just went ahead and upgraded my distribution, from 22.04 to 22.10, and that solved all my problems, at least temporarily. I was able to switch back to NVidia 515 and everything seems to be working!