# Why would Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy send a update for Nvidia 470 driver and warn it is better to update directly?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, updates

Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy nvidia update (Ubuntu Studio) has this update and a few like it: "This package contains the Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-52.

**You likely do not want to install this package directly**. Instead, install the one of the linux-modules-nvidia-470-server-lowlatency* meta-packages, which will ensure that upgrades work correctly, and that supporting packages are also installed."

I'm confused as why they would send a update and then say, "maybe you don't want to do this update (directly) that we sent you". Would you be able to tell me the best way to apply this update correctly, and if it is worth it? I have looked at some solutions online that were very complicated and had some trust issues. Here is one I found and was wondering if I am on the right path?
Update the package index:

```
# sudo apt-get update

Install linux-modules-nvidia-470-server-5.15.0-52-lowlatency deb package:

# sudo apt-get install linux-modules-nvidia-470-server-5.15.0-52-lowlatency
```

Comment: Probably related to all recent issues with Ubuntu / NVidia. I had the problem & only 1 screen (of 2) would show up & it was at 1024x768 (low res). I posted here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437047/kernel-update-wont-allow-nvidia-1660-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04-how-do-i-fix
And then I posted another one at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437490/are-new-updates-going-to-wreck-22-04-1-installation-running-nvidia-drivers?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

To update the software, you need to run the following command:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

This will update the software, including the metapackage that triggers the update of `linux-modules-nvidia-470-server-5.15.0-52-lowlatency`.

If it does not update (upgrade) that package, run the following command:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

To summarize, when you see that updates are available, run

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

to apply the updates.

---

It also should be noted that when you update or upgrade the packages using `apt upgrade` or `apt dist-upgrade`, they are installed as a dependency of the metapackages installed on your system.

As a dependency, these packages can be removed when they are no longer needed by running `sudo apt autoremove`.

However, if you install these packages directly, they will no longer be removed by the `apt autoremove` command if/when they are no longer needed in the future (after future updates).

This is why it's best to use the `apt upgrade` feature to update packages that are dependencies of metapackages rather than installing the dependencies directly.